# Minecraft Book triggers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to do something where you are reading a book and when you get to a certain page or finish the book, an event happens.

I'm making a horror adventure map and I was wondering if it was possible.

If so, what version of Minecraft should I use? Is 1.12.2 OK?

Answer (score 3):

### No.

It's not possible to trigger anything when the player reaches a certain page in a book.

The best you can do is to either

- trigger something whenever the player **opens** the book by having a scoreboard with the [`stat.useItem` statistic of the book](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Criteria) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Scoreboard&oldid=1264571#Criteria))
- or by letting the player click onto something in the book by giving the text in it a [click action](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Raw_JSON_text).

---

**Update in 1.14**: You can use a [lectern](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lectern) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Lectern&oldid=1363943)) instead of a book in the hand. A comparator getting a signal from it shows you the page it's currently on. The power level is the progress in the book spread evenly over the power levels 1 to 15.